# RestKit: requeue RKRequest in RKRequestQueue

Tags: ios, network-programming, restkit

I'm trying to implement an upload queue in my application. I'm putting my `RKRequest`s into `RKRequestQueue` and call `[queue start]`. But, as we all know, network connection is something that is not lasts forever. I'm using `RKReachabilityObserver` now to determine when to suspend and resume my queue, and it is working fine (at least now, however I've heard about some issues with reachability code in RestKit). This lets me to stop sending new data until network is available again. But when network connection is lost, all active `RKRequest`s are issuing `- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` where, I thought, I will be able to put my `RKRequest` back in queue again.

So, I tried this:

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Request failed");
    [[request queue] cancelRequest:request];
    [[request queue] addRequest:request];
}
```

but I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` somewhere in `didFailLoadWithError` method of `RKRequest`.

My question is: how can I requeue a `RKRequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cancelling and adding to queue, do:

```
[request send];
```

But the best solution for this would really be to use RKClient, it makes things easier. You would not have to worry about queue. The client comes with and instance of RKRequestQueue and does all the magic behind the scenes, specifically it adds all requests configured for the given client to the clients request queue and dispatches them for you.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this but I get `Attempting to add the same request multiple time` when I call `[request send]`. I've added `[[request queue] cancelRequest:request]` before sending the request again, and it seems it is working now.
Thank you once again.